# Displaying percentages in stacked bar Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

```javascript
// Display google stacked bar chart
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
role: "annotation"
},
2]);
```

Below is the picture of stacked [bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) I have.

[image]

I am not able to display the percentage on the green bar but not on the red bar.
The current value in the green bar is not a percentage value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need an annotation column for each series...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0,
  // series 0
  1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  },
  // series 1
  2, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }
]);
```

**EDIT**

to format the annotation value as a percentage

replace the `"stringify"` function with a custom function

use a [`NumberFormat` formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) to format the value

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawSeriesChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawSeriesChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Category A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Category B');
  data.addRows([
    ['Sep', 100, 190],
    ['Oct', 220, 178]
  ]);

  var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.0%'
  });
  
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,
    // series 0
    1, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 1) + ' (' + formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) / (dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2))) + ')';
      },
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    // series 1
    2, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 2) + ' (' + formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 2) / (dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2))) + ')';
      },
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, {
    isStacked: 'percent'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

UPDATED SCREENSHOT
[For reference to my COMMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Ziv.png)

Comment: Hello thank you very much! Got it solved! Do you know any way of how i can put the percentage value instead of the whole value?

Comment: Hello, I wanna thank you for taking off the time to write back to me! I However, the current situation is that it is taking the percentage of the value and not the actual percentage. So i just inserted for easier reference for you, is that i want to dispaly the percentage of 100% instead of 5%.And also, is it possible to put the percentages in the middle of the stacked bar instead of the extreme right?

Comment: changed percentage calculation in the __EDIT__ above -- as for label placement -- no standard options but can be achieved manually, when the `'ready'` event fires

Comment: Hello WhiteHat thank you for writing to me! It works super perfectly on mine! thank you once again!

Comment: Anyway, i was just wondering am i able to display both value and percentage? Is there any option where i can do that? Or is it purely based on only either one? @WhiteHat

Comment: sure, you can add whatever annotation you want, just change the return value of the `calc:` function

Comment: Hello, what you meant is that i have to change this return formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) / (dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2))) ? Or maybe you would like to show me in the snippet above? That will greatly help! @WhiteHat